# Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken. Error getting when I pass the json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to pass the checked check-boxes code to C# from JavaScript. I was able to send the code via JSON. And my JSON value comes as a JArray. And I am getting the exception in the title.

**JSON:**

```
{
  "Items": [
    "100066",
    "100067"
  ]
}
```

**C#:**

```
public ActionResult UpdateTransportRequests()       
{
    string json;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    JObject jo = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    string lineItems = jo.Value<string>("Items");

    RequestDataAccess rda = new RequestDataAccess();
    decimal reqId = decimal.Parse(lineItems);
    rda.ApproveReject_Request(reqId, "A", "");

    return Json(new { result = "success" });
}
```

**Client Side:**

```
function approveAll(requestid) {
    var items = [];

    $('#grid tbody').find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function (index, item) {
        var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
        items.push($('#grid tbody').find('tr:eq(' + rowIndex + ')').find('td:eq(1)').text().replace('TR-', ''));

    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTransportRequestsAll", "TransportRequest")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "Items": items }),
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.result);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: And that is the error?

Comment: I don't see a line converting JArray to a JToken...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this situation, I don't think `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is the appropriate method to use.  The error about converting from `JArray` to `JToken` likely occurs because `DeserializeObject` is attempting to directly deserialize to `JObject`, which will fail because it won't find the required fields on `JObject`.

Try using `JObject.Parse(json)` to get a `dynamic` object. You can use it like this afterwards:

```
dynamic jo = JObject.Parse(json);
var items = jo.Items;
foreach(var item in items)
{
    string lineItem = (string) item;
    decimal reqId = decimal.Parse(lineItem);

    // Use as required
}
```

Comment: @Vaithegi: if this answer was helpful to you, please don't forget to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 33):

It can be converted from JArray to List as `array.ToObject<List<TargetDataType>>();`

Comment: thats exactly what i am looking for

Comment: This really saves my time. Thanks, buddy.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult UpdateTransportRequests() 
{
    string json;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    dynamic jo = JObject.Parse(json);
    foreach (var item in jo.Items)
    {
        decimal reqId = (decimal)item;
        RequestDataAccess rda = new RequestDataAccess();
        rda.AllApproveReject_Request(reqId, "A", "");
    }
    return Json(new { result = "success" });
}
```